# What is the use of Cllipboard in Teamviewer?

Tags: teamviewer

Yesterday I was giving a session to my student of college project. Suddenly I got a message "26% saved to clipboard".  I am a bit confused with this message.  What does it mean during session.  Was my student trying to copy my project data w/o my permission. Please help me to understand this issue.

Comment: next time hit printscreen and open mspaint and get that screenshot in mspaint.  Then you can paste it into your question and it will help people answer. I googled "saved to clipboard" and teamviewer and didn't get anything so maybe you didn't get the wording right, or maybe it wasn't teamviewer. But either way, a screenshot of that message would help.

Answer (score 1):

The clipboard does what it does in Windows.  You can copy/cut and then paste from one pc to the other.  Your student may have accidentally pressed one of the following key combinations.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Ins</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>

If you are worried about it, you can disable the Clipboard.  I have mine disabled because if I want to copy a file on the remote machine from one folder to another, the clipboard intervenes and copies it to my local machine as soon as I have done a copy/cut.  It makes the session really really slow.

I would like the clipboard to work just for everything except files.  I have requested the developers to fix this.  But they just can not see why it is a problem.

This is where you can "Disable remote drag & drop integration"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you were sharing your screen/window, then he can't have done much without your seeing it.

E.g. Ctrl + C will copy whatever is selected to the clipboard, but he would have had to select something, first, which would have been visible to you.

More likely, he just hit (Alt + or Ctrl +) PrtScr a few times, as you were explaining things, to help him write up notes, later, and one of them lagged a bit, because of a connection hiccough.